# Code contracts - Rewriter fails with missing reference

Tags: .net-4.0, code-contracts

I'm trying to use code contracts for some libraries I have.  My library A has a reference to ThirdParty library B.  Library C references A, and never uses B nor does it use the bits of A that use B.  The rewriter fails though trying to find library B.  The reference assembly for A exists, I was hoping that the rewriter would be just happy with that.

Any ideas on how I can build this, short of moving the bits in A that rely on B out into its own assembly?

EDIT:  To answer a question, yes, there are public types in A which expose types in B.  I was hoping those the analysis would end at the library A, and that it would treat B as if there was no reference assembly at all (ie, ignore it).

Comment: Does the public interface for A include objects defined in B?

Comment: @Jeffrey L Whitledge:  I've updated my question which I hope clarifies things for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no way around this.  In some regards I think its good as it helps you see where your third party dependencies are leaking.